# Not able to delete azure apim api

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We have created the api inside apim which is using mock policy, in the response sample we have added the large json having 50k lines, now that api is not accessible through portal  nor able to delete that api. looks like some time out is happening. we tried from the powershell command Remove-AzureRmApiManagementApi, on running this command after 5 minutes it fails and gives error something like "command was cancelled"

Comment: What do you mean by "that api is not accessible through portal"? Please add a screenshot to illustrate. And what did you see when you tried to delete it?

Comment: 1. Normally when you open the API, on the right side Design view gets opened for that API. but in this specific api, after few minutes of clicking it it gives error on top right side saying 
"Could not load list of operations. Unexpected status code in SMAPI response: 504.. Please try again later.
Correlation ID: id"
2. when you try to delete it from portal, after few minutes i get the below error message on the top right side as notification: 
Unable to delete API <API_NAME>
Unexpected status code in SMAPI response: 504
Correlation ID: <id>

Comment: The server returns 504 time out. Please raise a support ticket on Azure portal. They should be able to delete the api for you.